# In Next-JS, UseEffect() is run twice. I put an empty array as the second argument, it did not help. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, frontend

In Next-JS, UseEffect() is run twice. I heard that you need to put an empty array as the second argument to fix this in React. In my case, in Next-JS, this does not work. (As far as I know, Next-JS is based on React).

I found one way: in next.config.js set reactStrictMode: false. And it works, the UserEffect is called once.

But this method does not suit me, because. I need to use React's strict mode.

_app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    useEffect(() => {

      console.log('Component Did Mount') //called twice :c

    }, [])


  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}


export default MyApp
```

Comment: Are you using react 18? If so, it is [expected behavior in strict mode](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors) that the component mounts twice, which means the effect will run twice.

Comment: btw, you can remove the condition. useEffect only runs client-side, so window is guaranteed to be defined. [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app#safely-accessing-web-apis)

Comment: From the react docs: Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: For a in depth answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/react-18-useeffect-is-getting-called-two-times-on-mount/72238236#72238236.

Comment: I believe this question should not be closed as a duplicate due to the fact that this is specifically for nextjs instead of vanilla react. I actually encountered this problem before in vanilla react and fixed it after seeing the questions this is marked as a duplicate of, but now that I started using nextjs, I had to refer specifically to this one for my solution because the answer in both is slightly different, although, I'll admit, very obvious.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

React.StrictMode is used to help during development, so why are you concerned about the double execution ?
By the way the *rules of hooks* say that you cannot place an hook inside a loop or an if statement.

Here are the code examples to address both issues:

1. NextJS to config [React's Strict Mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/react-strict-mode) edit `next.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
}
```

2. Move your if statement inside the `useEffect` hook

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        console.log('Component Did Mount') // called once
    }, [])

    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: For a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react.